# Can you glue vinyl cove base directly to drywall?

Tags: garage, baseboard

I'm installing [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/ROPPE-Blue-4-in-x-120-ft-x-1-8-in-Vinyl-Wall-Cove-Base-Coil-C40C83P187/205426749) vinyl cove base in my garage.

Garage walls currently do not have any kind of baseboards just drywall to the concrete.

Can I glue the cove base direct to the drywall or should I first install baseboards for more support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can glue them - that is really the only way to install them.   However I have redone quite a few garages...

I would just install azek or PVC trim boards - that's it.   Paint them whatever color you want and you install with finishing nails and don't have to worry about water (if done right they can protect your drywall from water on floor) and don't have to worry about pealing or replacing (you just repaint).

Not to dog vinyl cove (I have installed it commercially) but it really isn't a "home" product and it certainly shouldn't be used in areas that will see high temp and moisture changes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on any number of commercial installations I've seen (not personally installed) yes, this appears to be a very common practice.